# What is the correct way of setting state on a Vue 3 Pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

When initializing state on a Vue 3 (composition API) Pinia store which pattern is more "correct" or idiomatic?

**Option 1:**

```
  state: () => ({
    user: {},
  }),
```

**Option 2:**

```
  state: () => {
    return {
      user: {},
    };
  },
```

**Option 3:** Maybe something else?

Comment: They aren't different options. What you address here is basic JS syntax. It could be written as `state() {  return {...} }` and still would be the same.

Comment: you don't need any action before returning so option 1 is more like it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the same. Option 1 and 2 are functions that returns an object. In arrow functions, the `{` stands for the content of the function (like `function x () {`). So if you want to return an object (like `return {`), you would use `({` as option 1 does.

Reference: [Arrow functions advanced syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax)

Answer (score 4):

For the Vue 3 **Composition API** in Pinia, the correct pattern is:

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore('users', () => {
  const user = ref({});

  return { user };
})
```

It's called "Setup Store".

> In Setup Stores:
>
> `ref()`s become `state` properties
>
> `computed()`s become `getters`
>
> `function()`s become `actions`

More info: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores

Answer (score 1):

Option 2. It should be a functions that returns the state. https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html

Comment: Option 1 does that as well.